# Object refenrece not set to instance of an object - list template items

Tags: list, 2013, error, splistitem, visual-studio-2012

This may be a duplicate, because this error is pretty common in every part of sharepoint. However, the search function didn't find anything for my particular problem.

To the problem:
I have a List template which I want to use on a subsite. Creating the list and adding items works wonderful. Here is the list, which I'm talking about:

[image: The evil list]
Now the problem, when I click on a list item, for detail view or edit mode, it runs into a

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

exception. Here a picture of the error:
[image: Error message]

So, the funny thing is, when I get the list items via VS everything works fine and it receives the listitems as expected. See this picture:

[image: received list items via vs]

And as mentioned above, the list items are visible in the list itself. This error only occurs if you click on an item in the list.

Does anyone know, how to solf this issue?

thanks so far.
Jürgen

**Edit:**

Content type in request:
[image: IE]

In sharepoint designer:
[image: SPD]

Comment: What is ContentTypeId parameter in the request to EditForm.aspx/DisplayForm.aspx?

Comment: Also, does your list template contain content types?

Comment: I looked it up, the manifest of the list template does not contain the conent type id of any of those conents. However, there are some declared but no exact ids:

ContentTypeID="0x"

this is several times.
And the request id is the same. see edit in post

Comment: Could you provide your list template?

Comment: sure:
http://wikisend.com/download/365716/Idea List.cab

Comment: Workaround which works (for me). 
I made the same list now by hand, without a template and now it works, but still not working with a template :(